# Print lines in a file with delimiters

Tags: awk, sed

input.txt

```
hello
cruel
world
```

I want to print all the lines from the above file such that they have a beginning and ending string added along with a delimiter.

`BEGIN='`
`END='`
`DELIMITER=|`

Expected output:

```
'hello'|'cruel'|'world'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
hello
cruel
world
```

then

```
awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047",(NR>1?"|":""),$0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
'hello'|'cruel'|'world'
```

Explanation: I use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) with 2 places to fill (denoted to `%s`) and 2 `'` (as they have special meaning we must not use just `'` but escaped version, that is `\047`) and so-called ternany operator (condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse) to use `|` for lines after first (`NR>1`) and empty string for all else to fill 1st place and content of whole line (`$0`) to fill 2nd place.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)